# Why are some common nouns' first letters being used capital?

Tags: capitalization, proper-nouns

I am reading "**The Orphan Child**". On  the first page there is a sentence which seems fine to me. But I think I should clear the air and make sure am with the writer on the same page. My question is very simple, and I think I already know the answer as well. But before we move further I should write down the sentence so you can understand what exactly I am asking.

**Still from the novel:**

> Patterns of ice lingered on the outside of the *scullery window* at *Meadow* *Hall*....

My question is in the above sentence why the writer used the letter *M* and *H*  capital as *meadow* and *hall* are common nouns? And if you notice in the same sentence *scullery* and *window* both are also the common nouns but he didn't use the capital letters in this case. I gave the answer to myself and I said, "He used these nouns (Meadow, Hall) as proper nouns, and calling them by their names."

Does my answer make sense? Or am I wrong about it?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capitalization_in_English

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are right: Meadow Hall is the proper name of a house or mansion described in the book, and that is why the words are capitalized.

Note also that there is no article before "Meadow Hall": we don't usually use articles with proper nouns. We do have the definite article **the** before "scullery window", which somewhat attests to the fact that these words are common nouns (with "scullery" [used in an adjective role](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct)).

In *The Lord of the Rings*, Bilbo Baggins's house is called Bag End, for instance: the name is also capitalized, and again there's no article before it.

> The tale is structured as a journey to the Lonely Mountain (under which is the treasure trove) and back to **Bag End**, with a series of adventures along the way. (from Google Books)

Per PerryW's comment - there are exceptions to this pattern of "no article before the name of a building". The definite article is normally used before the names of pubs and bars: The Royal Oak, The Dover Castle, The Woolshed, etc.

According to BBC (["The" with place names: rules and exceptions](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv287.shtml)),

> But note that the names of most hotels and pubs, many theatres and cinemas and most museums and art galleries need to be used with the definite article.
>   - "Shall we eat at **the Goose**?"
>   - "No, I'm a vegetarian. Let's eat at **the Slug and Lettuce**."
>   - **The Filmworks** in Greenwich is a huge cinema complex next to **the Holiday Inn** on the Greenwich peninsula.
>   - **The National Gallery** is on the northern side of Trafalgar Square, opposite Nelson's Column. It's about a fifteen-minute walk from **The British Museum**.

Comment: @user62015 - you're welcome!

Comment: Great answer @CopperKettle but I'll take issue with one point just for the sake of pedantry. There is one very well known case where the definite article is normally used in a building name - pubs and bars, The Royal Oak, The Dover Castle, The Woolshed etc.

Comment: I think using the definite article with hotels and pubs is more of a British English thing. If the restaurant were called "Slug and Lettuce," I would say, "Let's eat at Slug and Lettuce."

Comment: The White House:  Building yes, but pub or bar?